# vhost_alias - how to map multiple parts to one folder?

Tags: apache

I'm using the following config:

```
ServerName dev.example.com
ServerAlias *.dev.example.com
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /dev.example.com/_virtual/%1/
```

This works fine for:

```
test.dev.example.com
```

which links to the folder

```
/dev.example.com/_virtual/test/
```

However, if I want to catch for example:

```
second.test.dev.example.com
```

Apache tries to find the folder:

```
/dev.example.com/_virtual/second/
```

**How can I make it find the following folder?**

```
/dev.example.com/_virtual/second.test/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the following VirtualDocumentRoot directive:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /dev.example.com/_virtual/%-4+/
```

**%-4+** means *the fourth-to-last part of the requested hostname, and all PREceding parts*

e.g., a request for this host (with some ascii art to indicate the position of each subdomain):

```
second.test.dev.example.com
5      4    3   2       1
^---------^
```

will get served from this directory:

```
/dev.example.com/_virtual/second.test/
                          ^---------^
```